# DB2 Select group matching condition and then do aggrgate listagg

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to fetch group of data that have a/c number in list and of last n months. But when i tried the below query, it is throwing me error !

sample data:

```
date      refnumber seq_no txt   load_dt
20200310  016       01     emp1  20200309
20200310  016       01     emp1  20200305
20200310  016       02     row2  20200309
20200310  016       02     row2  20200305
20200310  016       03     row3  20200309
20200310  016       04     act   20200309
20200310  016       04     act   20200305
20200310  016       05     row4  20200309
20200310  016       05     row5  20200309
20200310  018       01     emp1  20200309
20200310  018       01     emp1  20200305
20200310  018       02     row2  20200309
20200310  018       02     row2  20200305
20200310  018       03     row3  20200309
20200310  018       04     row4  20200309
20200310  018       04     row4  20200305
20200310  018       05     row5  20200309
20200310  018       05     row5  20200305
```

I need to check if `text contains act` and `load_dt is max of available load dt` and then fetch the entire group with those sequences and then concat all values

sample output:

```
date     ref_number message_txt              load_dt
20200310 016        emp1|row2|row3|act|row5  20200309
```

query i tried so far is:

```
SELECT
DATE, REFNUMBER,
LISTAGG(CAST(TEXT AS VARCHAR(30000)), '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(SEQ_NO AS INT)) AS MESSAGE_TEXT FROM <table>
WHERE (DATE(date) BETWEEN (DATE('2020-03-10')-18 MONTHS)  AND (DATE('2020-03-10')-1))
GROUP BY DATE, NUMBER
HAVING COUNT(
CASE WHEN text IN (comma separated list of records)
THEN 1 END
) > 0
ORDER BY DATE(DATE)
```

- When i tried for less number of months, it is working fine but **not eliminating duplicates**
- when i tried for say 18 months, it throws below error:

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1585, SQLSTATE=54048, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.71.22`

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Check out the error message

```
db2 ? SQL1585

SQL1585N  A temporary table could not be created because there is no
      available system temporary table space that has a compatible page
      size.
```

It clearly points you to the problem - contact the Administrator and ask him to add a temporary tablespace with the appropriate pagesize.

The support for distinct in listagg has been added in Db2 11.1 (for Unix Linux and Windows).
If you use another version or plattform for Db2 please specify it.

Comment: i just got to know there is going to be another field called load_dt and i need to retrieve the group that is recently loaded i.e ->  ```max(load_dt)``` which will remove duplicates....still trying this logic - not getting expected output

Comment: Not sure about your environment but try something like this WHERE load_dt = (select max(load_dt) from yourtable)

Comment: Thanks Michael, But I have to fetch the records of max(load_dt) of each date and now I solved this with a join condition. It is working fine now! The only issue I have is the temp table error...not sure how to contact the admin, is there any other work around...like first filter the groups then do aggregation? as the number of records after filtering will be very less and will be easy for concat...

Comment: Do not do workarounds these will always have drawbacks. There must be an option to figure the Admin out - you will need him anyway for other situations as well... Never underestimate what a DBA can do for you.

Comment: Yeah got it Michael, now i am planning to rewrite my query in hive :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this as is:

```
WITH TAB (date, refnumber, seq_no, text) AS
(
VALUES 
  ('20200310', '016', '01', 'emp1')
, ('20200310', '016', '01', 'emp1')
, ('20200310', '016', '02', 'row2')
, ('20200310', '016', '02', 'row2')
, ('20200310', '016', '03', 'row3')
, ('20200310', '016', '04', 'act ')
, ('20200310', '016', '04', 'act ')
, ('20200310', '016', '05', 'row4')
, ('20200310', '016', '05', 'row5')
, ('20200310', '018', '01', 'emp1')
, ('20200310', '018', '01', 'emp1')
, ('20200310', '018', '02', 'row2')
, ('20200310', '018', '02', 'row2')
, ('20200310', '018', '03', 'row3')
, ('20200310', '018', '04', 'row4')
, ('20200310', '018', '04', 'row4')
, ('20200310', '018', '05', 'row4')
, ('20200310', '018', '05', 'row5')
)

SELECT
  DATE, REFNUMBER
, LISTAGG(CAST(TEXT AS VARCHAR(3000)), '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(SEQ_NO AS INT)) AS MESSAGE_TEXT 
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(TO_DATE(DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')) AS DATE, REFNUMBER, SEQ_NO, TEXT
FROM TAB
--WHERE DATE(TO_DATE(date, 'YYYYMMDD')) BETWEEN DATE('2020-03-10') - 18 MONTHS AND DATE('2020-03-10') - 1
)
GROUP BY DATE, REFNUMBER
--HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN text IN (comma separated list of records) THEN 1 END) > 0
ORDER BY DATE;
```

The result is:

```
|DATE      |REFNUMBER|MESSAGE_TEXT                                                                                        |
|----------|---------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|2020-03-10|016      |emp1|row2|row3|act |row4|row5                                                                       |
|2020-03-10|018      |emp1|row2|row3|row4|row4|row5                                                                       |
```